# Issue with converting .py (Python) file to executable (Python 3.x)

Tags: json, api, python-3.7, executable

I coded a desktop app by using python 3 and it is an API data collection app. When I create the executable (.exe), it runs perfectly on my computer but when I open it on other computers, I get

> **Failed to execute script** message.

**Code** I only import the followings.

```
from tkinter import*
import requests
import json
```

Then I added the API as follows.

```
try:
#Connect the API to the .py code
    api_data=requests.get("https://www.hpb.health.gov.lk/api/get-current-statistical")
    api_json=json.loads(api_data.content)
    #Connect with variables
    lu_date= api_json['data']['update_date_time']
    lu_cases= api_json['data']['local_new_cases']
    lu_total= api_json['data']['local_total_cases']
    lu_hospital= api_json['data']['local_total_number_of_individuals_in_hospitals']
    lu_deaths= api_json['data']['local_deaths']
    lu_recover= api_json['data']['local_recovered']
    lu_rate1=int((lu_deaths/lu_recover)*100)
#Added some labels here
#Button
    ext_btn=Button(root, text="Exit", command=root.destroy,bg="red",fg="white",font="Helvatica 12 bold",padx=25)
    ext_btn.grid(row=8,column=0,columnspan=2)

    out = out.decode(encoding)

except Exception as e:
    api_json="Error"
root.mainloop()
```

I already tried the following method to execute it but it's not working. (by using command line and also the given GUI software)

```
pyinstaller -F codename.py
```

Comment: You're swallowing all errors. You might want to consider examining the exception that is likely being thrown.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable idea and I'll focus on exception handling more and improve the code. But this executable working fine on my computer which I used to coded but not on others

Comment: _"But this executable working fine on my computer which I used to coded but not on others"_ - right. That's way I asked to you examine the error which is almost certainly being raised. The text of the error may tell you why it's not working on another system. The first step in solving a problem is understanding the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable thoughts. I'm new to codings so I may make a mistake. Could you point me where I should check more on?

Comment: Add a print statement inside the `except` statement

Comment: I tried that as well but still, I'm getting **Failed to execute script** error and file doesn't open up.
I added following
`
except Exception as e:
    api_json="Error"
    lbl_err = Label(root, text=api_json, font="Helvatica 12 bold",fg="#0C1427")
    lbl_err.grid(row=0,column=0)
`

Comment: If there is a problem with tkinter, using tkinter to display the error won't work. Use a print statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the directions given. I tried print statement and the code has no bugs. 
I found the error and it was a tkinter issue I guess. 
I comment out following and problem solved
#root.iconbitmap('icon.ico')

Answer (score 0):

After so many researches and directions, I could be able to find the issue. Thanks, @Bryan Oakley for guidance. 
**The Issue**
It was a Tkinter issue and by removing icon import (window top left icon), I could resolve the issue.

```
#root.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
```

Also, I added a solid exception handling statement.